# Struts Project Deployed in Glassfish Retains Developer Information

Tags: glassfish, struts

I have an issue where a Struts project I have deployed in Glassfish retains my user details.

Basically upon accessing the webpage, the details of the user are used in the following statement:

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name").toLowercase;
```

Then this variable is passed to a class that runs through the database to find this name and bring back the relevant data.

I deployed this for the team to use and they keep bringing back my information from the database.

I have gone through the project and there is no reference to my username in there at all.

I am stuck on this to be honest, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... Let me see if I understand the issue. You've deployed a web app on a server. You're calling `System.getProperty("user.name")` in the app on that server. You expect it to return different user info based on the *client* that's calling the single app on a single server?

Comment: ......ahhhh, now i see. i was under the impression that the system.etc would get the client logon details.

Comment: I am looking on the web and the closest I can see is the principle method, would you reccomend that? or are you aware of an alternate?

Answer (score 0):

deploying an applet using the:

```
system.getProperty("user.name");
```

brings back current logged on user